# How can I overhaul a live MultiSite network?

Tags: multisite

I have a mess of a MS install that was basically a learning curve as I got it all going, about 400 sites running on it now. Countless crummy plugins have been run through it, some themes depend on plugins also. I can only image the nightmare in the database of artifacts etc.

I would like to overhaul this network, but need some help determining the best process.

Example, live network lives at `example.com` and every live sub site has a mapped domain. I would like to change the network URL to `example-prod.com` so that I can build the new network up on the actual URL of `example.com` if that makes sense. My thought is that because the live sites are mapped, it should not break anything...?

I would then setup and optimize the new network and then bring over all the subsites (somehow...) to run on the new theme and plugin infrastructure. Keeping the mapping and shutting down the mapping on the old, original `example-prod.com` network.

Does what I am attempting to describe make sense I hope? Has anyone done something similar or can offer a better approach?

Thank you.